# Can't find fundamental solution for $x^2 - 61y^2 = 1$ through continued fractions

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, continued-fractions, pell-type-equations

I'm trying to find the fundamental solution for the $n = 61$ case of Pell's equation $x^2 - ny^2 = 1$ through continued fractions. I know the lowest solution is $x = 1766319049$, $y = 226153980$, but the continued fraction expansion for $\sqrt{61}$ appears to miss the case where this pair of values for the nominator and denominator occurs. This upsets me because the Wikipedia page for Pell's equation explains that calculating the continued fraction for $\sqrt{n}$ should solve the problem. What am I doing wrong?

This is the code I'm using:

```
double r = sqrt(61);
unsigned long long h1 = 0;
unsigned long long h2 = 1;
unsigned long long k1 = 1;
unsigned long long k2 = 0;

for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
    unsigned long long b = r;
    unsigned long long temp = b * h2 + h1;
    h1 = h2;
    h2 = temp;

    temp = b * k2 + k1;
    k1 = k2;
    k2 = temp;

    r = (double) 1 / (double) (r - b);
}
```

Comment: The 22nd convergent for $\sqrt{61}$ is in fact precisely that pair.

Comment: Are you actually using *floating point arithmetic*???

Comment: Yes, I am, @LordSharktheUnknown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question (and to echo @LordSharktheUnknown's comment), what  you're doing wrong is right here:

```
double r = sqrt(61);
....
r = (double) 1 / (double) (r - b);
```

That number, $r$, that you're computing, is *not* $\sqrt{61}$. It's an approximation to it using double-precision arithmetic. Playing around with a different language, perhaps using floats instead of doubles, I find that $61 - r^2$, which should be $0$, is about $7 \times 10^{-15}$, which is definitely not zero. So you're finding (sort of) the continued fraction for a number that is *not* $\sqrt{61}$; you should not be surprised that the results you get are of little use in saying anything about $\sqrt{61}$.

Comment: Indeed the OP isn't even finding the CF of this number $r$, since at each iteration precision is lost....

Comment: This problem is harder than I thought. You cannot rely on floating-point numbers to calculate the sequence.

Comment: That's why I said "You're finding (sort of) ..." -- I didn't want to check the details, and it was at least possible that integer-and-double operations here were all exact by some miracle. :)

Comment: " You cannot rely on floating-point numbers to calculate the sequence." Indeed, that's the real point. A more general truth is that you can't rely on floating point numbers to do anything like exact arithmetic except in a few rare cases. I think that it's always true that $0.0 * x$ is exactly the same as $0.0$ in double-precision arithmetic. Beyond that, I wouldn't count on anything, at least not without reading the IEEE standard.

Comment: I use for my standard calculation 200 dec digits precision in Pari/GP . This helps for most current problems, for instance to get enough correct convergents for $\sqrt{61}$ to get the initial pair. This is not *always* enough, of course, but for me a useful default standard...

Answer (score 2):

Here is the "back of the envelope" way to construct the CF of $\sqrt{61}$.
$$a_0=\left\lfloor{\sqrt{61}}\right\rfloor=7$$
$$x_1=\frac1{\sqrt{61}-a_0}=\frac{\sqrt{61}+7}{12}$$
$$a_1=\left\lfloor{x_1}\right\rfloor=1$$
$$x_2=\frac1{x_1-a_1}=\frac{\sqrt{61}+5}3$$
$$a_2=\left\lfloor{x_2}\right\rfloor=4$$
$$x_3=\frac1{x_2-a_2}=\frac{\sqrt{61}+7}4$$
$$a_3=\left\lfloor{x_3}\right\rfloor=3$$
$$x_4=\frac1{x_3-a_3}=\frac{\sqrt{61}+5}9$$
$$a_4=\left\lfloor{x_4}\right\rfloor=1$$
$$x_5=\frac1{x_4-a_4}=\frac{\sqrt{61}+4}5$$
$$a_5=\left\lfloor{x_5}\right\rfloor=2$$
$$x_6=\frac1{x_5-a_5}=\frac{\sqrt{61}+6}5$$
$$a_6=\left\lfloor{x_6}\right\rfloor=2$$
$$x_7=\frac1{x_6-a_6}=\frac{\sqrt{61}+4}9$$
$$a_7=\left\lfloor{x_7}\right\rfloor=1$$
$$x_8=\frac1{x_7-a_7}=\frac{\sqrt{61}+5}4$$
$$a_8=\left\lfloor{x_8}\right\rfloor=3$$
$$x_9=\frac1{x_8-a_8}=\frac{\sqrt{61}+7}3$$
$$a_9=\left\lfloor{x_9}\right\rfloor=4$$
$$x_{10}=\frac1{x_9-a_9}=\frac{\sqrt{61}+5}{12}$$
$$a_{10}=\left\lfloor{x_{10}}\right\rfloor=1$$
$$x_{11}=\frac1{x_{10}-a_{10}}=\sqrt{61}+7$$
$$a_{11}=\left\lfloor{x_{11}}\right\rfloor=14$$
$$x_{12}=\frac1{x_{11}-a_{11}}=\frac{\sqrt{61}+7}{12}=x_1$$
and here the periodicity kicks in: $x_{n+11}=x_n$ and $a_{n+11}=a_n$ for $n\ge1$.
So the CF is
$$[7,1,4,3,1,2,2,1,3,4,1,14,1,4,3,1,2,2,1,3,4,1,14,\ldots].$$

Note I have only used two-digit integer arithmetic to calculate the CF. In 
general for a non-square positive integer $d$, the $x_n$ in the CF
for $\sqrt d$ will have the form
$$x_n=\frac{\sqrt d+b_n}{c_n}$$
where $b_n$ and $c_n$ are positive integers, and $c_n\mid(d-b_n^2)$.

Of course in this example, to compute the convergents one still needs integer
arithmetic, but with more than two digits.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. So I can rely on multiplying by the conjugate to keep only one square root expression and have that at the top and an integer as the denominator. Now I think I know how to solve problem 66 at Project Euler.

Comment: Is it possible to prove that all x terms will be of exactly that form?

Comment: @MånsNilsson yes

Comment: Here is a check for that.  Whenever you render the square root of a whole number there's the first term which is the integer part, the end of the period which is twice the first term, and everything in between.  The digits in-between are always palindromic like 1,2,1 in $\sqrt{19}=[4,\overline{\color{blue}{1,2,1},8}]$.

Answer (score 1):

The period of the continued fraction expansion for $\sqrt{61}$ is $11$, and that convergent, $\frac{p_{11}}{q_{11}}=\frac{29718}{3805}$, yields $-1$. Thus the solutions to the Pell equation $x^2-61y^2=1$ are $\frac{p_{22}}{q_{22}}$, $\frac{p_{44}}{q_{44}}$, $\frac{p_{66}}{q_{66}}, \ldots$.

Comment: So I am wrong to use the formulas h_n = a * h_(n−1) + h_(n-2), k_n = a * k_(n−1) + k_(n-2) for every following fraction in the sequence?

Comment: I get 7/1, 8/1, 39/5, 125/16, 164/21, 453/58, 1070/137, 1523/195, 5639/722, 18440/2361 and 42519/5444. I don't get your continued fraction.

Comment: It looks like you've got $a_9=3$, instead of the correct value $a_9=4$. @MånsNilsson

Answer (score 0):

There are 53 integer bits
in a double-precision floating point number.

$x^2 > 10^{18}
\gt 2^{59}$
and this is more digits
than can be exactly computed.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on rogeri's answer, once the minimum solution $\;(p_{22},q_{22})\;$ is computed, the other solutions may be alternatively (and perhaps more easily) computed via

Define $(P_k,Q_k)\;$ by $\;\left(p_{22} + q_{22}\sqrt{61}\right)^k\;$
is equal to $P_k + Q_k\sqrt{61}.\;\;$

Then $\;(P_2,Q_2) = (p_{44},q_{44}), 
\;(P_3,Q_3) = (p_{66},q_{66}), ...$